# TYPO3 Fluid - Exit a for loop

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is it somehow possible to break out of a for loop in fluid?

```
<f:for each="{subItem.image}" as="imageItem">
 <f:if condition="{selectedCategory} == {subItem.imagecategory}">
  Do Stuff
  Exit loop
 </f:if>
</f:for>
```

I need to loop trough a couple of images then render one if the category matches and exit the loop after that since I only want to render the first image with the matching category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fluid variable view helper:

```
<f:variable name="imageRendered" value="0" />
<f:for each="{subItem.image}" as="imageItem">
 <f:if condition="{selectedCategory} == {subItem.imagecategory} && {imageRendered} == 0">
  Do Stuff
  Exit loop
  <f:variable name="imageRendered" value="1" />
 </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me, but all in all I consider this a rather bad solution in terms of performance since the loop continues to the end of the array. But I guess there is no other way to do this, so thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a dataprocessor to give you an array with just the images in the category, and then you can just grab the first image with `{imageItem.0}`.

Have a look at `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor`.